# Arranging div with css

Tags: html, css, nav

I've a little problem with arranging nav/div on a website. Google didn't revealed me a solution, but to be honest, I didn't really know how to search for it...

**What I'd like to have at the end:**
On the left side, a `<nav>` (data selection) is visible. On the right side, several `<div>` (graphs) are shown like a table with 2 columns and infinite lines, resp. max. two graphs side by side. The field of the `<nav>` shall be independently which means no `<div>` from the right side should be **below** of the `<nav>`.

How I have to implement the css file?

If you click this hyperlink, you'll see the current situation of the arrangement:
[Screenshot of the nav and the divs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1fesssmzp2nkft/nav_VS_div.jpg)

Later on: the goal is to realize a Drag&Drop behavior as described here: [HTML5 Drag&Drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp). It should be possible, to drag the data from the `<nav>` and to drop it into any of the graph-`<div>` for visualization.

Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried? Post code

Comment: Post you html, css and make a fiddle of your code

Comment: Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dszy8/1/). It's without the Diagram-Visualization, but I put a name instead to see where the divs are located. Otherwise I have to import rickshaw.js and its specific css and so on.

Comment: Why not use plain old floating, like here http://jsfiddle.net/P9CbZ/? P.S. - sorry, didn't see you fiddle, I hope you'll figure out, how to make the appropriate changes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*CSS*

```
nav {
    width:30%;       //<----Occupying 30% of total width, change it as required
    float:left;
}
#charts-wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:68%;       //<----Occupying 68% of total width and occurs on right of nav, change it as required
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.charts {
    float: left;
    width:32%;       //<-----Equal area within charts
    margin-left:0.5%;
}
```

### [*Demo Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/dszy8/4/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS try:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: I tried, but without success. Where exactly should I use `display: inline-block;`? [Fiddle-link to see my css](http://jsfiddle.net/dszy8/1/) The css part for the <nav> is a bit confusing for me, because there are several "blocks" which are used...

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from reading your question you would like to have a navigation bar on the left and another container with images/graphs on the right?

Here is a js fiddle I put together quick demonstrating floats: http://jsfiddle.net/HzS3m/1/

```
HTML:
<body>
    <nav id="nav">
        <a href="#">HTML</a>
        <a href="#">CSS</a> 
        <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        <a href="#">jQuery</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="graphs">
        <img src="#">
        <img src="#">
        <img src="#">        
    </div>
</body>

CSS:
nav{
    width:20%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#f00;
    float:left;
}

#graphs{
    width:80%;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:#ff0;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
}

img{
    width:300px;
    height:90px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Floats are a good way to align html/div elements side by side.

Hope this is of some help to you.